# How do I default the "Number Formatting" drop-down option in QlikSense to "Number"?

Tags: qliksense

In my Excel export from Qlik Sense, it is defaulting numbers to Scientific Notation. The NUM() function isn't doing the trick in this case. When the "Number Formatting" drop-down is "Number" the Excel exports to the correct format. Is there anyway to make this the default option for all Measures in Qlik?

[image: I need "Number" to be the default setting instead of "Auto"]

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately there's no way to do this in the current version of Qlik Sense. Hopefully they'll release an update where master measures can have a default number formatting, but for now you have to do it per measure per object...

Comment: Drats, okay! Thank you.